# Ruby: Get the CPU from the top -n1 output (un)

Tags: ruby, regex, linux, string

I want to save the output from this for example:

```
%Cpu(s):  9,0 be,  2,5 sy,  0,2 ni, 88,2 un,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
```

into a interger, but I only need the number before the "un" chars. It's the output of top -n1 of a Linux Server. The numbers of the output change every second.
Btw. sry for my bad english...

Comment: why don't you try awk or sed?

Answer (score 0):

An integer cannot hold a fraction number like `88,2`. For a floating point number, you could use

```
output = "%Cpu(s):  9,0 be,  2,5 sy,  0,2 ni, 88,2 un,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st"
number = output[/[0-9,]* un/].tr(',', '.').to_f
```